# Python Matplotlib Add 2 Dynamic Title Components

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib, dynamic, title

I have 6 subplots that need 2 dynamic title components and I can code for 1 but I'm not sure how to change my code below to add a 2nd dynamic title component on the same line after searching the literature. Here is my for loop to generate the 6 subplots with the "plt.title.." line below:

```
list = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
now = datetime.datetime.now()
currm = now.month
import calendar
fig, ax = plt.subplots(6)
for x in list: 
   dam = DS.where(DS['time.year']==rmax.iloc[x,1]).groupby('time.month').mean()#iterate by index of 
   column "1" or the years
   dam = dam.sel(month=3)#current month mean 500
   dam = dam.sel(level=500)
   damc = dam.to_array()
   lats = damc['lat'].data
   lons = damc['lon'].data
   #plot data
   ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   ax.coastlines(lw=1)
   damc = damc.squeeze()
   cnplot = plt.contour(lons,lats,damc,cmap='jet')
   plt.title('Mean 500mb Hgt + Phase {} 2020'.format(calendar.month_name[currm-1]))
   plt.show()
   #plt.clf()
```

I need to add one of each from this list in the loop to the "plt.title.." between the "+" and the word "Phase" line above...?

```
tindices = ['SOI','AO','NAO','PNA','EPO','PDO']
```

Thank you for any help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing the `tindices` one by one and passing them to the title

```
plt.title('Mean 500mb Hgt + {} Phase {} 2020'.format(tindices[x], 
                                                     calendar.month_name[currm-1]))
```